# PHP send data to some other webpage

Tags: php, post, get

I want to have a script on one website and database on other website.

First website has 2 fields where they enter username and password. Then php posts username/password to other php file and that php does *something* and then somehow sends the data to my second website, where I insert username and password to MySql database.

So I can do everything except:

I have 2 variables in PHP file, and I want to send them to other webpage, which gets them with maybe $_POST ? Also posting should be automatic, so the script posts them itself not via button press. How to do it?

Is my question clear? I can explain.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear at all, actually.

Comment: something has to trigger the posting of data. What exactly do you mean by automatic? Please clarify

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why don't you want this script on your website?

Comment: Seems clear enough to me. He wants to send a POST request to a PHP script hosted on another server from his own PHP script.

Comment: @boug : automatically. i mean..lets say my programs gets 2 values from user input.then manipulates them and changes them .. now php has these values, but now after, php has done its job, i want it to send those values to other website

Comment: @Lotus Notes : thats exactly what i want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't your script on your dummy website retrieve the data via $_POST and then call the script from your real website?

http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Check that out. This way your can POST to your real website from your dummy site's script, completely transparent to the user.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP cURL library to send these kinds of data requests.

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

There are three obvious ways to do this:

1) Simple – keep the page hosted on site 2, but use an iframe on site 1 to embed it.

2) Post the form from site 1 to site 2 by setting the action attribute to a script on site 2.

3) Post the form on site 1 to a script on site 1, then use CURL to post it to the other site behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * create request || application/json
 * @param $method
 * @param $url
 * @param $args
 * @param $isSentBody
 * @param $cert
 * @return resource
 */

function createRequest($method, $url, $args, $isSentBody, $cert = false)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if ($method == 'POST')
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($args));

    if ($isSentBody) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($args));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            //'Authorization : Bearer ' . getAccessToken(),
        ));
    }
    if ($cert)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . $cert);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    try {
        return curl_exec($ch);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```